# How to check search results of website on google?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, ovh

I am working on a website "https://datasiplus.com".
When i type datasiplus on google, i get as 3rd result this url "https://datasiplus.com.cutestat.com/".
Is it normal ?
Can it be the cause for my website having unwanted popup ads ?

Comment: Did you develop this site under `.cutestat.com` domain? If you did and you didn't check `Discourage Search Engines From Indexing` in settings then it was indexed.

Comment: no i didn't develop this site under .cutestat.com

Answer (score 1):

#### How to check search results of website on google?

You can see all indexed pages from your website (domain) if you go to google search and type the following

`site:datasiplus.com`

#### cutestat.com is it normal?

This page is a tool to get information about a specific domain. It's estimating the value, traffic and lot more. Either this tool has automatically crawled your page or someone searched for your domain with it.
There is a form on their site, where you can request to remove your domain from cutestat.com [here](https://www.cutestat.com/remove)

So yes, it's normal that this is in google index because it's like a subpage of their tool and `datasiplus` is a keyword for both sites, yours and datasiplus.com.cutestat.com

If you go to google now and search for `datasiplus`, then you can already see your own question there.

#### Can it be the cause for my website having unwanted popup ads?

No, this page will not cause unwanted popup ads on your page (or any other page).
Popups like this is most probably caused by malware on your page. This may be introduced through some security holes in wordpress and / or from one of the plugins you are using.
To get started to search and remove such malware, you can start at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668011/wordpress-malware-how-do-i-remove-it)